# How to convert an Object {} to an Single Dimenstion Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I have an Object like :

```
{"1": "Biraz", "2": "Dahal", "3": "Arjun", "4": "Abhis"}
```

into an single dimension array-like this:

```
["Biraz", "Dahal", "Arjun", "Abhis"]
```

I tried using

```
var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [obj[key]]);
```

by this, I got the result as

```
[["Biraz"], ["Dahal"], ["Arjun"], ["Abhis"]]
```

How can do that in a signle array?

Comment: `Object.values(obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const object = {"1": "Biraz", "2": "Dahal", "3": "Arjun", "4": "Abhis"}

const array = Object.values(object)

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj={
    "1": "Biraz", "2": "Dahal", "3": "Arjun", "4": "Abhis"
};
const arr = Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

And also in your code, you can use the join method to join and split them:

```
const arr = [["Biraz"], ["Dahal"], ["Arjun"], ["Abhis"]];
var a = arr.join(" ");
var original_arr = a.split(" ");
console.log(original_arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the [] inside callback function of map.

```
var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => obj[key]);
```

Comment: @georg, no idea why people downvote it. It works but it is not a straightforward way compared to ```Object.values()```

Comment: @ikhvjs: sure, but it tells the OP what they did wrong, which might be helpful.

Comment: there are so many impatient guys. why did they downvote?